# In-place merge two sorted array

Tags: java, algorithm

First post.

Can you please review my code and help me improve my coding. Please also suggest improvements if there is a miss in this post.

> Problem Statement
>
> Given two sorted arrays `X[]` and `Y[]` of size *m* and *n* each, merge elements of `X[]` with elements of array `Y[]` by maintaining the sorted order.
> i.e. fill `X[]` with first *m* smallest elements and fill `Y[]` with remaining elements.
>
> Input:
> X[] = {1, 4, 7, 8, 10}
> , Y[] = {2, 3, 9}
>
> Output:
> X[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 7}
> , Y[] = {8, 9, 10}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] X = {11, 14, 17, 18, 110};
    int[] Y = {112, 113, 114};

    mergeRunner(X, Y);

    System.out.println("X: " + Arrays.toString(X));
    System.out.println("Y: " + Arrays.toString(Y));

}

private static void mergeRunner(int[] x, int[] y) {

    if (x[x.length - 1] > y[y.length - 1]) {
        merge(x, y);
    } else {
        merge(y, x);
    }

}

private static void merge(int[] x, int[] y) {
    final int m = x.length;
    final int n = y.length;

    int last = x[m - 1];
    int i = m - 2;
    for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

        while (i >= 0 && x[i] > y[j]) {
            i--;
        }

        //Insertion
        insertValue(x, i + 1, y[j]);

        y[j] = last;
        last = x[m - 1];

        //System.out.println("X: " + Arrays.toString(x));
        //System.out.println("Y: " + Arrays.toString(y));
    }

}

private static void insertValue(int[] x, int index, int valueToInsert) {

    int i = x.length - 1;
    while (i > index) {
        x[i] = x[i - 1];
        i--;
    }
    x[i] = valueToInsert;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, at the moment your code cannot be reviewed because it does not match the description of your task you provided, for further details you can check [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I have seen you edited your question so now description of the task and code match , for clarity I have edited your post separating description of the task from the code.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, but the problem you proposed can be solved in a less complicate manner, starting from your example these are some steps of my algorithm making comparisons between elements of the two arrays:

```
x = [1, 4, 7, 8, 10} , y = [2, 3, 9] step0 : comparing 10, 9
                  ^               ^

x = [1, 4, 7, 8, 9} , y = [2, 3, 10] step1 : 10, 9 swapped
                 ^                ^

x = [1, 4, 7, 8, 9} , y = [2, 3, 10] step2 : comparing 9, 3
                 ^            ^
       
x = [1, 4, 7, 8, 3} , y = [2, 9, 10] step3 : 3, 9 swapped 
                 ^            ^

x = [1, 3, 4, 7, 8} , y = [2, 9, 10] step5 : reordered x with swaps, comparing 8, 9
                 ^            ^
```

This means that if you start from the right of the two arrays, if the `x` array element is greater than the array `y` element, the swap will be done and after you will reorder the `x` array swapping adiacent elements if one element is smaller than previous element in the array.

With the help of a method to swap elements between the two arrays like this below:

```
private static void swap(int i, int j, int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int tmp = arr1[i];
    arr1[i] = arr2[j];
    arr2[j] = tmp;
}
```

Your method  `mergeRunner` can be rewritten like below:

```
private static void mergeRunner(int[] x, int[] y) {
    final int maxIndex = x.length - 1;

    for (int j = y.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {

        if (y[j] < x[maxIndex]) {

            swap(maxIndex, j, x, y);

            for (int i = maxIndex; i > 0 && x[i - 1] > x[i]; --i) {

                swap(i, i - 1, x, x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (How did you assess correctness of your suggestion (disregarding the assumption `y.length <= x.length`)?)

Comment: @greybeard Hello, because the initial scenario includes the two sorted arrays and after every step of the algorithm the two arrays still remain always sorted indipendently from the fact I'm exchanging or not the elements (I'm will reorder the 'x' array in case of exchange). I'm not changing array initial dimensions `m` and `n`, so the algorithm brings the result expected by OP.

Comment: (I noticed you never change `maxIndex` (not having declared it `const`), got 2nd thoughts. Not very likely I'll look into this in earnest.)

Comment: @greybeard  I got it, because the arrays are always ordered at every step I always compare `y` elements with the max element of `x` (`x[maxIndex]`) to do eventually a swap , I missed setting  `maxIndex` to `final`, thanks for the advice.